Я пытаюсь внедрить карту с маркерами на сайт. Использую Яяндекс API V3 но почему то у меня некак не получается создать маркеры на карте
вот мой js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var points = [
        { name: 'Москва, Красная площадь', coords: [45.28185357458866, 38.83058549999994] }
    ];

    var input = document.getElementById('address');
    var suggestions = document.getElementById('suggestions');
    var map;

    input.addEventListener('input', function() {
        var query = this.value.toLowerCase();
        suggestions.innerHTML = '';

        if (query.length > 0) {
            var filteredPoints = points.filter(function(point) {
                return point.name.toLowerCase().includes(query);
            });

            filteredPoints.forEach(function(point) {
                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.innerHTML = point.name;
                div.addEventListener('click', function() {
                    input.value = point.name.split(',')[0]; // Передаем только имя места, без координат
                    suggestions.innerHTML = '';
                    map.panTo([point.coords[0], point.coords[1]], { duration: 500 });
                });
                suggestions.appendChild(div);
            });
        }
    });

    async function initMap() {
        await ymaps3.ready;

        const { YMap, YMapDefaultSchemeLayer, Placemark } = ymaps3;

        map = new YMap(document.getElementById('maps'), {
            center: [45.28185357458866, 38.83058549999994], // Ваше местоположение в точке Москвы
            zoom: 14,
            controls: ['zoomControl', 'searchControl', 'typeSelector', 'fullscreenControl', 'routeButtonControl']
        });

        map.addControl(new ymaps3.ZoomControl());
        map.addControl(new ymaps3.SearchControl());
        map.addControl(new ymaps3.TypeSelector());
        map.addControl(new ymaps3.FullscreenControl());
        map.addControl(new ymaps3.RouteButtonControl());

        map.addChild(new YMapDefaultSchemeLayer());

        points.forEach(function(point) {
            var placemark = new Placemark(point.coords, {
                balloonContent: point.name
            });

            placemark.events.add('click', function() {
                input.value = point.name;
                map.panTo([point.coords[0], point.coords[1]], { duration: 500 });
            });

            map.geoObjects.add(placemark);
        });
    }

    initMap();
});

и мой html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/page/baket/style.css">

  
  <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/V3/?apikey=8669b2f4-adc5-417d-a735-9f2f03dd0be4&lang=ru_RU"></script>
  <script src="/page/baket/baket.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="map" id="map">
    <div class="fa-solid fa-circle-xmark"></div>
    <iframe
      src="https://yandex.ru/map-widget/v1/?um=constructor%3A991360c683b2e9a6ded089e9d95dbf3384853f2a95e7898a0dd7ee303122970e&amp;source=constructor"
      frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </div>
  <main>
    <!-- heder -->
    <div class="heder">
      <!-- nav -->

      <nav>
        <!-- logo -->
        <h1>COFFEE</h1>
        <!-- /logo -->
        <!-- menu -->
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/index.html">HOME</a></li>
          <li><a href="/page/coffee/index.html">Menu</a></li>
          <li><a id="shop-butt" href="#">SHOP</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">LOGIN</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- /menu -->
        <!-- search -->
        <div class="box">
          <form action="" method="get">
            <input class="search_input" id="search_input" name="search" type="search">
          </form>
          <button class="search" id="search"><i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"
              style="color: #fff; font-size: 1.2rem;"></i></button>
        </div>
        <!-- /search -->
      </nav>
      <!-- /nav -->
    </div>
    <!-- /heder -->
    
    <!-- baket -->
    <div class="baket">
        <div class="lokation-search">
            <input class="lokation-search"  id="address" name="search" type="search">
            <button class="lokation-searchButt"><i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"style="color: black; font-size: 1.2rem;"></i></button>
            <button id="suggestions" style="width: 100%;"></button>
        </div>
        <div id="maps" style="width: 100%; height: 50em"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- /baket -->

    <footer>
      <h2>Coffee</h2>
      <table>
          <th>PRIVACY</th>
          <th>SERVICES</th>
          <th>ABOUT US</th>
          <th>SOCIAL MEDIA</th>
          <tr>
              <td>Privacy Policy</td>
              <td>Shop</td>
              <td>about us</td>
              <td><i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i><i
                      class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i><i class="fa-solid fa-paper-plane"></i></td>
          </tr>
      </table>
  </footer>
  </main>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2585aabbee.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- <script src="/main.js"></script> -->
</body>
</body>

и ее величество ошибка
 at n.geoToMercator (main.js:1:39883)
    at r.type.toWorldCoordinates (main.js:1:40829)
    at M (main.js:1:59980)
    at ii.B35_createCamera (main.js:1:177954)
    at new ii (main.js:1:176748)
    at rs.D98_createMap (main.js:1:224863)
    at new rs (main.js:1:219709)
    at initMap (baket.js:37:15)

baket.js этой мой js файл конкретно вот эта строчка map = new YMap(document.getElementById('maps'), {

Потому что для 3й версии многое делается иначе. Параметры обернуты в loсation, вместо Placemark - YMapMarker. Должны быть преднастроенный слой YMapDefaultSchemeLayer и слой геообъектов YMapDefaultFeaturesLayer. У вас же смешение 3 со 2й.
Об этом можно посмотреть в документации Руководство разработчика - объекты на карте


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const markerProps = [{
      coordinates: [37],
      iconSrc: 'https://yastatic.net/s3/front-maps-static/maps-front-jsapi-3/examples/images/marker-custom-icon/yellow-capybara.png',
      message: "I'm yellow capybara!"
    },
    {
      coordinates: [38, 55],
      iconSrc: 'https://yastatic.net/s3/front-maps-static/maps-front-jsapi-3/examples/images/marker-custom-icon/purple-capybara.png',
      message: "I'm purple capybara!"
    },
    {
      coordinates: [37, 55],
      iconSrc: 'https://yastatic.net/s3/front-maps-static/maps-front-jsapi-3/examples/images/marker-custom-icon/green-capybara.png',
      message: "I'm green capybara!"
    }
  ];

  async function initMap() {
    await ymaps3.ready;

    const {
      YMap,
      YMapDefaultSchemeLayer,
      YMapDefaultFeaturesLayer,
      YMapMarker
    } = ymaps3;

    const map = new YMap(document.getElementById('maps'), {
      location: {
        center: [37, 55],
        zoom: 10
      }
    });

    map.addChild(new YMapDefaultSchemeLayer());
    map.addChild(new YMapDefaultFeaturesLayer());

    markerProps.forEach((markerProp) => {
      const markerElement = document.createElement('img');
      markerElement.className = 'icon-marker';
      markerElement.src = markerProp.iconSrc;
      markerElement.style.width = '40px'
      markerElement.onclick = () => alert(markerProp.message);
      map.addChild(new YMapMarker({
        coordinates: markerProp.coordinates
      }, markerElement));
    });
  }

  initMap();
});
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/v3/?apikey=8669b2f4-adc5-417d-a735-9f2f03dd0be4&lang=ru_RU"></script>
<div id="maps" style="width: 100%; height: 200px"></div>



